# PhoneStateListener() isn´t finished

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

I implemented a PhoneStateListener how stops audio if you are called and starts it again after you finished.
When i exit my app by finish() the PhoneStateListener seems to be still active. After finishing a call the music starts to play.
Even if I set the listener=null in onDestroy() it keeps working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the documentation for `listen()` on [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html):

> To unregister a listener, pass the listener object and set the events argument to LISTEN_NONE (0).

You must do this before your activity goes out of scope, such as in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`.

Comment: If I call this: mTelMan.listen(mCustomStateChangeListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE); in onDestroy() of service.. It somehow mess up lifecycle of service.. what we are doing wrong here?! Thanks