# What MUST go inside onDestroy()? (if anything at all)

Tags: android

Right so here I am obsessing over memory leaks, and quite frankly not understanding what could really lead to one (and yes I've read the usual links such as http://kohlerm.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/memory-leaks-are-easy-to-find.html).

I've tried to create some on purpose, for example by leaving a PhoneStateListener subclass inside my activity and opened and closed it a bazillion time, can't see anything in DDMS heap or MAT out of the ordinary. Yet on SO I read over and over again that not only it needs to be deregistered onDestroy, but also onPause ([PhoneStateListener() isn´t finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607344/phonestatelistener-isnt-finished))

Question: is there such a list?
Bonus question: is it true that a PhoneStateListener will create leaks unless it's deregistered onPause/onDestroy etc.

**UPDATE:**  I stand corrected. When re-spawning my app over and over again, even in singleinstance mode, the PhoneStateListener(s) it has registered are still alive after onDestroy was called, and start adding up. I'm currently working on an elegant way to kill them, and will post my results here.

**UPDATE2:** The correct way to deregister the listener is:
   instanceOfTelephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
... according to the API

**UPDATE3:** As promised linking this to a better phrased question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4607435/821423

Comment: The only thing that you should always put in `onDestroy()` if you override it is `super.onDestroy()`, just to answer your title :)

Comment: If you can reproduce it you are a lucky programmer. The `onDestroy` is a callback method called when your activity is destroyed. So depending on your activity code, you might release here resources.

Comment: About the listener, `onPause` is called always before `onDestroy`, so it makes no sense to call it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice for activity to clean up after yourself and prepare to die in onPause() - this is always called before it goes out of focus, and can not interact with  user.  onDestroy() is possibly called after this (but not guaranted).

Is your activity is not in focus for user,  it does not need any listeners anymore, as it can not show results of those listeners.

Comment: Agreed but it doesn't appear to be a definitive list of what could somehow have references still pointing at your activity... So the listeners are one, I found that out above, the question is: is there anything else?

Comment: onPause() is the only callback which is guaranted to be called - so anything serious shall be released there. I would thred onDestroy as counterpart to onCreate() , but in my applications there is nothing that shall be cleaned up there, as I onlz rig up user interface in onCreate()